# Which woocommerce plugin should i use for my need?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, user-permissions, user-roles

I have this client who has a subscription plan system. For example, with the premium pack you have access to 4 magazines + 1 video + 1 free magazine.
So i have to set a limit of product to my cart per user role, and multiple rules per products.
I have found some interesting plugins but none was covering my needs. I guess i'll have to use a combo of severals plugins.
I was just wondering if any of you have ever heard or used a plugin like this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So i've decided to go for this combo:

- http://codecanyon.net/item/ultimate-membership-pro-wordpress-plugin/12159253
  To setup my subscriptions packs and give and take users roles
- https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/
  To create these roles
- http://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-prices-by-user-role/8562616
  To set the prices to 0 after their subscriptions
- http://www.varktech.com/woocommerce/maximum-purchase-pro-for-woocommerce/
  To set the rules of quantity of products in the cart according the user role

To some of you that needs to set the same logicals conditions, be aware that you'll need those in their PRO version, so you'll have to pay it.